# Laravel passing all routes for a particular domain to a controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Working on a Laravel 4.2 project. What I am trying to accomplish is pass every URI pattern to a controller that I can then go to the database and see if I need to redirect this URL (I know I can do this simple in PHP and do not need to go through Laravel, but just trying to use this as a learning experience.)

So what I have at the moment is this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'sub.domain.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('?', 'RedirectController@index');
});
```

I am routing any subdomain which I deem as a "redirect subdomain" ... The `?` is where I am having the problem. From what I have read you should be able to use "*" for anything but that does not seem to be working. Anyone have a clue how to pass any URL to a controller?

And on top of that I would ideally like to pass the FULL URL so i can easily just check the DB and redirect so:

```
$url = URL::full();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'sub.domain.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('{path}', 'RedirectController@index')
        ->where('path', '.*');
});
```

And your controller will reseive the path as first argument

```
public function index($path){
    // ...
}
```

In case you're wondering, the `where` is needed because without it `{path}` will only match the path until the first `/`. This way all characters, even `/`, are allowed as route parameter

Comment: Worked like a charm. Exactly what I needed. Didn't think to use the where clause after the route itself.  Thanks man!